# Android Searchable Dictionary word loading question

Tags: android, sample

I'm stepping through the android Searchable Dictionary example, and I can't find the place where it actually loads the words into the sqlite db.  I would think it happens in the onCreate method of DictionaryDatabase.java, but this never seems to be called.  And yet the app works!

Also, I couldn't get it to work at all until I commented out lines 41-42 of strings.xml, which was giving me this error:

Description Resource Path Location Type
error: Found tag  where  is expected strings.xml /SearchableDictionary/res/values line 41 Android AAPT Problem

TIA,
Joel

Ha!  So it looks like onCreate is only called when the db is first created, as it was the first time I ran the app.  I deleted the db manually and it was recreated next time I ran the app:

from within adb shell:
rm /data/data/com.example.android.searchabledict/databases/dictionary

I still don't know why the strings.xml file causes an error, but I'm moving on :)

Answer (score 0):

Just for clarification is this
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SearchableDictionary/src/com/example/android/searchabledict/DictionaryDatabase.html
the same source, you're talking about?
If yes, then indeed it does load in onCreate() method, which is for their initial setup, though I can't help you with the xml.
Good luck